# Qué significa que una condición if sólo tenga return

Tags: javascript, condiciones

¿Qué significa el siguiente código?

```
if(condicion) return;
```

Simplemente así, no tiene llaves y no dice qué retorna. Simplemente *return*.

Comment: Si la condición se cumple, se termina la ejecución de la función en la que se encuentra dicha sentencia. Es usado para salir de la función y no seguir ejecutando el código que venga a continuación. En Javascript, una sentencia `return` devuelve `undefinded` por defecto. Saludos

Comment: Gracias mauricio...

Answer (score 8):

Pues tal como te digo en mi comentario, sirve para terminar la ejecución del método, función o incluso script (programa). Todo dependerá del ámbito en el que se encuentre dicha sentencia.

Tu duda también está enfocada a la falta de las llaves de bloque (`{` y `}`) que usualmente acompañan a la sentencia `if`, además que la sentencia `return` se encuentra en la misma línea que inicia la sentencia `if`.

**Llaves de bloque**

Resulta que las llaves sirven para limitar un bloque de código. Sin embargo, las mismas sólo resultan **necesarias** cuando existe más de una instrucción en dicho bloque de código.

El intérprete de Javascript necesita las llaves de bloque para *comprender* que el conjunto de instrucciones que se encuentran dentro de dicho bloque serán ejecutadas secuencialmente si se cumple la condición. Hasta aquí eso ya lo sabemos de antemano. Sin embargo, si el bloque se compone de una sola instrucción, se pueden omitir las llaves. Por ejemplo las siguientes instrucciones son equivalentes:

```js
const valor = true;
// con llaves de bloque
if(valor) {
  console.log("Debo mostrarme");
}
if(!valor) {
  console.log("No me veo");
}
// sin llaves de bloque, siguiente linea
if(valor)
  console.log("También debo mostrarme");
if(!valor) {
  console.log("No me veo");
}

// sin llaves de bloque, misma linea
if(valor) console.log("Y yo también");
if(!valor) {
  console.log("No me veo");
}
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  min-height: 100%;
  top: 0;
}
```

Como se aprecia en el código anterior, el resultado es el mismo sin importar el uso de separador de bloque o no, incluso si la llamada a `console.log` se encuentra en la misma línea que la sentencia `if`.

¿Y cuándo es **necesario** el uso de las llaves?

Cuando el bloque a ejecutar tiene más de una sentencia, es necesario usar llaves. Por ejemplo:

```js
const valor = true;

if(!valor)
  console.log("No debo mostrarme");
  console.log("Yo tampoco debo mostrarme");
  
if(!valor)
  console.log("Yo menos"); console.log("Ni yo");
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  min-height: 100%;
  top: 0;
}
```

Como se observa, la primera línea es omitida porque es parte del bloque `if`, y al no existir llaves de bloque esa es la única línea que no se ejecuta, la siguiente línea ya no está dentro del bloque semántico de `if`, por lo tanto se ejecuta.

Te puedes ver tentado a escribir 2 sentencias en la misma línea, pero ello indica que debes usar `;` como separador de sentencias, ya que de no hacerlo te daría un error `SyntaxError`. Precisamente ese carácter `;` indica el fin del bloque `if`. Es decir, si se cumple la condición, se ejecutará todo lo que hay en el bloque delimitado con llaves. Si no hay llaves se ejecutará la primera sentencia que se encuentre después del `if`, ya sea que se encuentre en la misma línea o en la siguiente. El separador de sentencias puedes omitirlo si escribes las sentencias en líneas diferentes, en caso de que no exista un separador de sentencias, se toma el carácter de nueva linea como separador de sentencias. Es por ello que no puedes escribir más de una sentencia en la misma línea sin dicho separador, con las excepciones de los códigos que ejecutan bloques, como `if` o `for`.

Por ejemplo:

```js
let sum = 0;

for(let i = 0; i < 5; ++i) sum++;

console.log(sum);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  min-height: 100%;
  top: 0;
}
```

**Sentencia `return`**

La sentencia `return` es una sentencia especial del lenguaje e indica el *retorno* o salida de la llamada a la función o programa. Viene de *retornar* o devolver el control al proceso que ha llamado a dicha función o programa. Podemos añadir un argumento a dicha sentencia para *devolver* ese valor al proceso que ha llamado a la función.

Cuando no pasamos un argumento a `return`, Javascript asigna el valor `undefined` por defecto como valor devuelto por la función.

El uso de la sentencia: `if (condicion) return;` es muy común. Es una forma de salir de una función si se cumple una condición específica, con la cual no tendría sentido seguir ejecutando el resto de la función.

Por ejemplo, si tengo una función que valida si un valor es entero o no, podría tener lo siguiente:

```js
const valida = function(v) {
  if(v === undefined || v === '') return;
  return Number.isInteger(v);
}
let valor;
console.log(valida(valor));
valor = 5;
console.log(valida(valor));
valor = 5.3;
console.log(valida(valor));
valor = '';
console.log(valida(valor));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  min-height: 100%;
  top: 0;
}
```

Como se aprecia, si el valor de entrada de la función es `undefined` o `null` o es una cadena vacía, no se ejecuta el resto de la llamada y se sale de la función. Si no es el caso, se continúa ejecutando la misma y se devuelve un resultado.

Es por ello que muchas veces se utiliza este tipo de sentencias de una sola línea, hacen el código un poco menos engorroso de leer y mantenible. Pero como todo, no debemos abusar de sintaxis tan reducida ya que puede ser contraproducente.

Comment: tambien aplica que para salirse de la estructura for, foreach, while, do-while o switch usar `break;` sin la necesidad de salirse del metodo/funcion.